# Autocorrelated Returns?

Tags: time-series, econometrics, autocorrelation, autoregressive, vector-autoregression

I'm trying to compute some VAR models for the Amgen Pharmaceutical company (NasdaqGS: AMGN), however I've noticed that the daily returns seem to be significantly autocorrelated at a number of lags (here I'm using $AR(5)$). My (limited) understanding is that returns of assets are supposed to be uncorrelated, and therefore I'm really struggling to understand why this is the case.

The data I'm using (available at the link below) is daily adjusted close prices from 01/01/1995 to 31/12/2014 comprising 5036 observations in total.

http://finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=AMGN&a=00&b=1&c=1995&d=11&e=31&f=2014&g=d

I calculate returns based on:

$r_t = \log \frac{P_t}{P_{t-1}}$

And the autocorrelations (calculated in R) are:

```
     Lag 1: -0.0462
     Lag 2: -0.0627
     Lag 3: -0.0328
     Lag 4:  0.0298
     Lag 5: -0.0311
```

Although the correlations are small, they are statistically significant, based on $0 \pm \frac{1.96}{\sqrt{5036}} $.

Is there anything that I need to do with the returns to reduce the autocorrelation?

Comment: Could it be an extreme event, or a few of them, causing these autocorrelations? What if you take a rolling window and look at autocorrelations there, are they consistent and similar to the whole-sample autocorrelations?

Comment: Hi @RichardHardy, I'm actually looking at 10 different pharmaceutical companies covering the same period. 9 of these 10 companies are exhibiting significant autocorrelation amongst returns and lagged returns. Weirdly, the 2nd day lag is significant in all 9 companies.

Comment: In my previous comment, I try to provide a plausible explanation for this and a way to elicit it. Also, look at the size of the autocorrelations. Perhaps they are statstically but not economically significant, i.e. perhaps you could not have made money (due to transaction costs) even if you were aware of their presence.